# LINQ to XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm creating a simple application that download XML and parse it. I have a problem with these:

```
<image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/101313093.jpg</image>
<image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/101313093.jpg</image>
<image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/101313093.jpg</image>
<image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/101313093.jpg</image>
```

By default code:

```
var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("user")
           select new User
           {
               Image = (string)query.Element("image")
           };
```

It always download an uri to small image, but I want to download a large.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var result= xdoc.Descendants("image")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("size").Value == "large")
                .Select(x => new User{ Image =  x.Value });
```

Here is [Working Example Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IQYP5j)