# I want to display the first node XML attribute on form?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this XML file:

```
<tree>
<grand name ="tom"  id="1" sex="m" status="d" child="2" father=""  /> 
<grand name="adam"  id="11" sex="m" status="d" child="1" father="1"   /> 
<grand name="john"  id="111" sex="m" status="d" child="1"  father="11"   />  
<grand name="pierre"  id="1111" sex="m" status="d" child="3"  father="111"   />  
<grand name="jan"   id="11111" sex="f" status="d" child=""  father="1111"  />  
<grand name="marc"    id="11112" sex="m" status="d" child=""  father="1111"  />  
</tree>
```

I try this code to display attribute of the first node only on load the form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XDoc.Load("F:\\tree.xml");
    XmlNode att = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//grand/@name");
    string nam = att.ToString();
    label1.Text = att;
}
```

But I get nothing.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using linq and [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("F:\\tree.xml");  
var result= xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("name").Value;
label1.Text = result;
```

or filter on `id` attribute [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125345/how-to-select-an-attribute-in-xml-based-on-the-value-of-another-attribute).

you have to include `System.Xml.Linq` namespace for it.

Comment: you may also need to put an @ before the filename

Comment: Yes @Kevin we need that if we use single backslash, we are using two here so no need of @